# My cursor appears in wrong position, after adding blockquote with CSS

Tags: android, html, css, cursor

I am using a blockquote for example:

```
<blockquote>This is an example</blockquote>
```

And then a custom CSS to have a style like below:

```
blockquote{
  font-size: 18px;
  //margin: 0 auto;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: open-quote;
  display: inline;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 3em;
}
blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
  display: inline;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

But I have issus with the appearance of cursor. I have tried something like: `cursor: none !important;` It looks like I can not hide it.

Please see this video of how it looks like and it is annoying. At this moment you can write on two positions of cursor, please check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvkg0ffAbkk&list=UUxPNH2JpfFTtkB2muKQ7zjA) in order to better understand what I mean.

Comment: where have you tried putting the cursor:none property?

Comment: In css both "blockquote:after {" or" blockquote{"

Comment: have you tried the contenteditable="false" property on the blockquote?

Comment: User should be able to change text, so it should be editable.